# SAS\SQL group by and count by..finding the first and last and comparing

Tags: sql, sas

I have an issue i am stuck on trying to sort out...i basically have a table that looks a little something like this..

```
ID    user    operation     date
1     Jon     In         01/01/2013
1     Paul    Out        02/01/2013
1     Paul    In         03/01/2013
2     Jon     Deleted    04/01/2013
2     Paul    In         05/01/2013
2     Jon     Out        06/01/2013
1     Jon     out        07/01/2013
1     Jon     Deleted    08/01/2013
2     Jon     out        09/01/2013 
1     Jon     in         11/01/2013
```

So basically i need to find where for the same ID both Jon and Paul are "In". So in the example about Jon and Paul are both in for ID 1, and for ID 2 i will only find Paul. So the last known date for that row has to be included as the early in, out or deleted is it be ignored as it was later changed. So in short i need to find ID values where an IN existes and that has not been later set to "out" or Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your objective is not clearly stated; it is hard to tell what you want to do.  It will be easier for people to help if you illustrate.  Using the sample data provided, show an example of final result you want.  And welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Hi sorry for not making it clear,

Comment: Hi sorry for not making it clear, so in short if for that user an operation of out or deleted exists for that ID then ignore it however if an operation of IN exists for that same ID and USER later on then it is fine. So basically if an IN operation exists for the same ID but for different users then i want it to be output. So the result will be ID    user    operation     date
'1     Paul    In         03/01/2013
2     Paul    In         05/01/2013
1     Jon     in         11/01/2013' @Bob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you sort the data correctly then using first. in a data step should work (unless you have an id and user with more than 1 entry on the same day, you'd need to determine which one to take if that were the case).

```
data have;
input ID user $ operation $ date :mmddyy10.;
format date mmddyy10.;
cards;
1     Jon     In         01/01/2013
1     Paul    Out        02/01/2013
1     Paul    In         03/01/2013
2     Jon     Deleted    04/01/2013
2     Paul    In         05/01/2013
2     Jon     Out        06/01/2013
1     Jon     out        07/01/2013
1     Jon     Deleted    08/01/2013
2     Jon     out        09/01/2013 
1     Jon     in         11/01/2013
;
run;

proc sort data=have;
by id user descending date;
run;

data want;
set have;
by id user;
if first.user and lowcase(operation)='in' then output;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code is ad hoc for your specific question and data.  It would be somewhat more complex, though not impossible using macro logic, to generalize the code to work for any number of users.

```
proc sort data=original_dataset;
   by date id user operation;
run;

data results_dataset;
   set original_dataset;
   retain _jon _paul 0;
   drop _jon _paul;
   if trim(left(lowcase(operation))) eq 'deleted' then delete;
   else if trim(left(lowcase(operation))) eq 'in' then do;
      if trim(left(lowcase(user))) eq 'jon' then _jon = 1;
      else if trim(left(lowcase(user))) eq 'paul' then _paul = 1;
   end;
   else if trim(left(lowcase(operation))) eq 'out' then do;
      if trim(left(lowcase(user))) eq 'jon' then _jon = 0;
      else if trim(left(lowcase(user))) eq 'paul' then _paul = 0;
   end;
   if (_jon eq 1) and (_paul eq 1) then output;
run;
```

Comment: What if there are two records that have "in" status and doent have an out or deleted for either. Will this bring them to the output dataset?

Comment: Yes. If you want to see the logic at work, then remove the "DROP _JON _PAUL;" line and then print out the data set.